# Measurability of a supremum

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

I have been wondering if the following supremum $\varphi$ is measurable..

Let's say we have a metric space $X$ and a parameter space $\Theta$, which is *compact metric space*. $\{f_\theta: \theta \in \Theta\}$ is a collection of Borel measurable functions defined on $X$, such that for any fixed $x \in X$, the function $\theta \mapsto f_\theta(x)$ is continuous on $\Theta$. Now define $\varphi(x) = \sup_{\theta \in \Theta} f_\theta(x)$. Is $\varphi$ measurable? Or there are some counterexamples?

Any hint will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but since one can show that phi is measurable if the index set is denumerable, using that compact metric spaces are separable, the continuity hypothesis could lead to the conclusion that phi is independent of the chosen dense subset.

Comment: Great hint! I forgot that separability follows immediately :-)